# rotating matrix ninety degrees clockwise

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose  $A$  is an $m \times n$ matrix and  $B$  is the  $n \times m$ matrix obtained by
rotating  $A$  ninety degrees clockwise on paper (not exactly a standard mathe-
matical transformation!). Do $A$ and  $B$  have the same singular values? Prove
that the answer is yes or give a counterexample.

My confuse is that I cannot find relations between $A$ and $B$, especially the relation between their column vectocs. So please give me some ideas.

Comment: I think $B$ Is obtained by taking the transpose of $A$ and then reversing the ordering of all columns of $A^T$.  So you can find a relationship between singular values of a matrix and its transpose, and between a matrix and the matrix formed by reversing its columns.

Comment: Yes you are right. But how to represent this order reversing？

Comment: No need to formally represent it...as long as you can prove something about its singular values. If you like, for a given matrix $A$, you can say $Rev(A)$ is the column-reversal of $A$.  For example, it is clear that the column spaces of $A$ and $Rev(A)$ are the same.

Comment: @Michael Thank you for your hint! And I think I can solve this problem by your method..

Comment: Left-multiplying by $\pmatrix{0&0&\cdots&0&1\\0&0&\cdots&1&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\0&1&\cdots&0&0\\1&0&\cdots&0&0}$ will accomplish the column flip. In general, left-multiplying a matrix by the $k$-th row of the identity picks out its $k$-th row; right-multiplying by the $k$-th column of the identity picks out its $k$-th column.

Comment: @amd I thnk you mean right-multiply but +1 anyway.

Comment: @Michael I was thinking that the contents of each column were to be flipped. If we’re want to reverse the order of the columns, then indeed right-multiplication by this matrix will do it.

Comment: It might be worth noting that a 90° clockwise rotation in $\mathbb R^2$ is equivalent to a pair of reflections—in the lines $x=-y$ and then $x=0$—which is basically what we’re doing to transform this matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I think this answer might work.

Denote the $r$th row vector of $A^T$ as $a_j^T=(a_{j1}, \cdots, a_{jm}).  \quad j=1,\cdots, n $

So from the information given in the problem,  the $r$th row vector of $B$ is $\hat{a}_j^T \triangleq  (a_{jm}, \cdots, a_{j1})$

By using $SVD$ of $A^T$ we have $A^Tv_j=\sigma_j u_j$.  $\Longrightarrow a^T_k v_j=\sigma_j u_{kj}\quad k=1,\cdots, n \Longrightarrow$

$\hat{a}^T_k \hat{v}_j=\sigma_j u_{kj}$. Since $v_{j}$ are orthonormal basis in $\mathbb C^n$, $\hat{v}_j$ is also orthonormal, which means the singular values of B are equal to $A^T$. And the singular values of A are equal to $A^T$, since $A=U\sum V^*\Longleftrightarrow A^T=\bar{V}\sum^T U^T,$ $U$ and $ V$ are unitary$ \Longleftrightarrow \bar{V}$ and $U^T$ are unitary.

Therefore the singular values of A are equal to B.

Comment: Sounds good.  Or using the @amd method you can say $B=A^TP$, where $P$ is that given permutation matrix, and work it that way.

Comment: Yeah, this is a good idea!